# Is there a flexible "cloth-like" material that can be used as "skin" for a non-conventional wing?

Tags: wing, aerospace-materials, composite-materials, amateur-experimental, ornithopters

I am in the very early stages of playing with the idea of an [ornithopter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter) derived aircraft. The intention is to be able to scale the resulting aircraft, to passenger (or useful payload) carrying capability.

Is there any material that is simultaneously light - but also strong enough to carry the weight of an aircraft (and it's payload)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aircraft fabric would be too heavy for a person carrying homebuilt orni-contraption.  What you are looking for is 3M Mylar/Tedlar.  It has been used as a covering material for a number of ultralights like the Lazair for many years.

Comment: can a material like [spandex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandex) be used instead of 3M Mylar - as the former is more readily available, cheaper and also crucially has great elasticity.

Comment: It has to be impermeable.  And you don't really want elasticity, just flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Am I right in concluding from your answer, that - if I'm able to find impermeable spandex (i.e. airtight), such material would be suitable for use as wing skin (i.e. in terms of weight/strength)?. 

Does such material (airtight spandex) exist?

Comment: As I said, stretchy=bad.  Spandex would be no good.

Comment: No idea.  You need to select some different products and test them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cloth has been used for wings since the first powered flights. It is usually doped with a resin to make it less permeable to air.